# Nonlinearity of a Boolean function with odd number of input bits

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher

Highly nonlinear functions are used in combination generators and other stream ciphers.

We know that maximum nonlinearity (hamming distance to all affine functions) of $f$ is achieved when $f$ is bent function. This will be
$$NL=2^{n-1}-2^{(n/2)-1}$$ when $n$ is even. Also when $n$ is odd, this bound is not satisfied. What will it be?

The question is: *Can we find $f$ with largest nonlinearity for an arbitrary odd integer $n$ case?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a famous open problem in coding theory, *the covering radius of the first order Reed-Muller code, when the number of variables is odd.*

As far as I know the best general upper bound on nonlinearity which in this paper is denoted N (=covering radius R) for $n=2k+1$ is still the one below:

[image]

Comment: Since the question (quickly deleted) was relevant to crypto and not asked before, I resurrected it.